# Entity Framework Database Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, foreign-keys

Dear Entity experts and others,

I have the following entities,

**Base class Individual:**

```
 public abstract class Individual
    {
        [Key]
        public int IndividualID { get; set; }
        ... other properties
    }
```

**Yogi:**

```
 [Table("Yogis")]
    public class Yogi : Individual
    {
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthdate { get; set; }
    }
```

**Customer:**

```
[Table("Customers")]
public class Customer : Individual
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VATID")] // tried with and without
    public virtual VAT VAT { get; set; }
}
```

**VAT:**

```
public class VAT
{
    [Key]
    public int VATID { get; set; }     

    [Required]
    public virtual Customer VATHolder { get; set; }
    ... other properties
}
```

DbContext:

```
  public DbSet<Individual> Individuals { get; set; }
  public DbSet<VAT> VATS { get; set; }
```

So the above creates a table VAT where there VATID is 2 to start with which should be 1 instead, I don't understand why this happens, this should be 1, isn't it? Also, there is no reference anywhere in any table that references Customer & VAT, how can I create a separate table VAT_Customer where you have a VATID & CustomerID ?

This is how i create and insert the entity Customer:

```
        VAT vat = new VAT("123456789");
        DataBaseHandler.InsertIndividual(new Customer("Customer name", vat,...));
```

**Insert Function:**

```
public static void InsertIndividual(Individual individual)
    {
        using (MyDbContext ctx = new MyDbContext())
        {               
                ctx.Individuals.Add(individual);    
                ctx.SaveChanges();                                    
        }
    }
```

I have tried several ways ([EXAMPLES HERE](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)) but I prefer the TPT way, having a separate view of any entity or relations between entities. What am I doing wrong and how would I achieve the desired result? Let me know if I can clarify anything. Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

Kind regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ForeignKey placement should look something like this if you wanna have 1:1 Relationship :

```
enter code here
[ForeignKey("VAT")] 
public virtual int VATId { get; set; }
public virtual VAT VAT { get; set; }
```

Name in the ForeignKey is same as your class.

hope this can help

Comment: also you don't need  (Customer ) in Vat class ,, you can access it from the customer direct

Comment: if your customer has more than 1Vat ,, add this to your customer class :
        public virtual List<VAT> VATS{ get; set; }

Comment: Customer can only have 1 VAT nr so its like you said a 1 one 1. I did the following: **Removing Customer from the VAT class:**
- Makes ID from VAT 1 instead of 2 (GREAT!)
- Adds a column name in Customer table VAT_VATID (GREAT!)

    [ForeignKey("VAT")]
    public virtual int VATID { get; set; }
    public virtual VAT VAT { get; set; } 
This gives me a VATID column in the Customer tables which till now is the best result i have seen. Is there any way to map them seperatly to a table, like CUSTOMER_VAT where there would be a VATID and CUSTOMERID ?

Comment: in 1:1 relationship you don't need that however , you can a new table and add :

 public class CustomerAndVat
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VAT")]
        public virtual int VATId { get; set; }
        public virtual VAT VAT { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Customer ")]
        public virtual int CustomerID{ get; set; }
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

but this a M:M table Relation !

Comment: hmm you are totally right Rashid, i was confused and maybe overthinking and working to long on it, as it is 1:1, i don't need a seperate table for it. But thank you so much for your help and clarification it helped me alot ! Kind regards !